# wcf upload/download large files (i.e. Img, mp3) in chunks with windows service

Tags: wcf, file-upload, windows-services, chunks

I have a window service and i want it to be able to upload/download large (around 4MB) files (Img, music etc.) in chunks.
I tried to do that by changing the 'maxBufferSize' 'maxRecivedMessageSize' etc. in both the service and client app.config files, but unfortunately it didn't work.
My question is how I can upload/download files in chunks. and if I can do that just with the App.config file?
Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF doesn't have direct support for chunking (it always sends whole data as single chunk) but you can check this [extensibility example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx) to get chunking channel. Both your service and client must use that channel to make it work.