# Using web service to send large object (ex. image bitmap)

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm trying to use WCF web service in C# to send the bitmap data of an image to the client, I plan to send this as an object. I want to understand the nature of web service.

My question  is how does this work with a large file? such as 10MB?  Does web service work in one single request/response to send all 10MB worth of bitmap data?  What if a network error occurs? will the client have to reissue the request?

The reason I ask this is I have been working with Socket and often when it comes to large file, I break it down to trunk of manageable size (such as 4kb) and then send it, if one succeed then I'm sending the next 4kb until all the data are transferred.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same principle can be applied here. You can send it in chunks. Related post you might find usefull - [wcf upload/download large files (i.e. Img, mp3) in chunks with windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723976/wcf-upload-download-large-files-i-e-img-mp3-in-chunks-with-windows-service)

Comment: Thank you, so to get that done it needs the participation of the client as well which I think defeat the whole purpose of web service (that is implement once and let many use it).  I have no need to send it in chunks so I will stick with the full 10MB message ..